# Export WAS 8 config to a Jython script?

Tags: websphere, jython, websphere-8

I was wondering if it's possible to generate automatically a Jython script from a WAS 8 configuration for all the ressources, env var, etc?

Similar to the WebSphere administrative commands showing the jython command issued.

Thanks,
M

Comment: Well, it's possible to write a Jython script for it, but the topic is very broad (including practically all AdminConfig objects)

Comment: As opposed to just using the `backupConfig` script. That would indeed be useful and informative.